# Satisfiability with DP and DPLL yields different results

Tags: logic, sat, satisfiability

I have the following clauses:

```
1. {P,Q,~R}
2. {~P,R}
3. {P,~Q,S}
4. {~P,~Q,~R}
5. {P,~S}
```

I have to prove the satisfiability using DP and DPLL separately. The problem is that I am getting different results for each algorithm.
With DP:

```
1. {P,Q,~R}
2. {~P,R}
3. {P,~Q,S}
4. {~P,~Q,~R}
5. {P,~S}
6. {Q} from 1 and 2

2. {~P,R}
3'. {P,S}
4'. {~P,~R}
5. {P,~S}
7. {P} from 3' and 5

2. {R}
4'. {~R}
8. {}
```

So it is unsatisfiable. But with DPLL:

```
1. {P,Q,~R}
2. {~P,R}
3. {P,~Q,S}
4. {~P,~Q,~R}
5. {P,~S}
6. {P} split(P)

2'. {R}
4'. {Q,~R}

7.{Q}
```

Which would mean it is satisfiable... What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In the first inference in DP, the resolution rule is not applied correctly. Let's focus of the inference of `6. {Q} from 1 and 2` from `1. {P,Q,~R}` and `2. {P,Q,~R}`. The assignment of P, Q, and R to false satisfies `{P,Q,~R}` and `{~P,R}`, but it does not satisfy `{Q}` which the inference is are claiming is entailed by the previous two. The possible resolvents of `{P,Q,~R}` and `{~P,R}` are:

- `{Q, ~R, R}` by resolving on `P`
- `{P, Q, ~P}` by resolving on `R`

Both of these clauses are always true and are discarded by DP. (Discarding is sometimes called the tautology rule.) These do not entail `{Q}` as shown in the previous counter example.

Also note that on the DPLL example, you have assigned P, R, Q to true. This is inconsistent with clause `4. {~P,~Q,~R}`. Unit propagation needs to be applied exhaustively for this split.

You can find many presentations of DP and DPLL online. Examples: [1](https://www.fi.muni.cz/%7Epopel/lectures/complog/slides/davis-putnam.pdf), [2](https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/%7Ekb/MACTHINGS/SLIDES/2013Notes/1LDP4up13.pdf). Try to apply the rules consistently and exhaustively.

Comment: Oh alright, so when you have two pairs of complementary literals you can only remove one?

Comment: The resolution rule eliminates 1 variable at a time. You can try to work out whether what you are suggesting is true. Consider resolving {A, B, C} with {~A, ~B, D}. You can check with a simple true table that there are cases where these clauses are both true while {C, D} is false. (A, ~B, ~C, ~D is such an assignment.) So you can conclude that the variant of the resolution rule you are proposing is not a sound inference.